# Infobox not working

Tags: infobox

I'm not a developer and i'm trying to learn javascript step by step. Now, I need to add a simple infobox in the gmaps that I'm working on. The problem is that, I add the code as explained in the google reference but it doesn't work: in the beginning i was using infowindow wich worked well but wasn't so customized. I also put the infobox.js link in that page and it is the last release.

This is test page: http://www.squassabia.com/aree_espositive_prova2.asp

What i need to do is to display the message you see in the code (boxText.innerHTML), just to understand it step by step and to keep things simple. After that I'm going to style it and add data from xml (which I think is not going to be that difficult).

As i didn't fint any solution in any of the old posts, if anyone of you can give me a clue on how to solve the problem, would be very appreciated, I've tried everything and put infobox stuff pretty much everywhere :(

Cheers

I give you the initialize() code:

```
//icone custom
var customIcons = {
  negozio: {icon: '/images/gmaps/mc.png'},
  outlet: {icon: '/images/gmaps/pin_fuc_outlet.png'},
  sede: {icon: '/images/gmaps/pin_fuc_home.png'}
};

var clusterStyles = [
{
textColor: 'white',
url: '/images/gmaps/mc.png',
height: 48,
width: 48
}];


function initialize() {

//creo una istanza della mappa
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapp"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.405, 9.867),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    saturation: 20, //scrollwheel: false
  });


//stile della mappa
var pinkroad = [ //creo un array di proprietà
  { 
    featureType: "all", //seleziono la feature
    stylers: [{gamma: 0.8 },{ lightness: 50 },{ saturation: -100}]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road.highway.controlled_access",
    stylers: [{ hue: "#FF3366" },{ saturation: 50 },{ lightness: -5 }]
  }
];
map.setOptions({styles: pinkroad});

var name;

//Creates content and style
var boxText = document.createElement("div");
boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
boxText.innerHTML = "Prova Infobox<br >Successo!!Test Text";

var myOptions = {
             content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)         
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: {background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat", opacity: 0.75, width: "280px"}
            ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false

        };

var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);


//creo il marker
downloadUrl("xml/negozi.xml", function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
  {  
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("tipo");
    var address = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("indirizzo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var city = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("citta")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var phone = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("telefono")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    name = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("nome")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

    var html = name + '<br />' + address + '<br />' + city + '<br />' + phone;
    var icon = '/images/gmaps/pin_fuc.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: point, icon :'/images/gmaps/pin_fuc.png'});

    /*google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click", function(){ 
        map.panTo(this.position);
    });*/

    createMarkerButton(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        ib.open(map);
    });

   }  

});

function createMarkerButton(marker) {
  //Creates a sidebar button
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    ul.appendChild(li);

  //Trigger a click event to marker when the button is clicked.
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(li, "mouseover", function(){
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    setTimeout (function (){marker.setAnimation(null);}, 750);
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(li, "mouseout", function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "mouseout");
  });

}


}


 function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
 var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
  new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
  new XMLHttpRequest;

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
  request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
  callback(request, request.status);
}
 };

 request.open('GET', url, true);
 request.send(null);
 }

 function doNothing() {}
```